# Countif a number have days have passed since date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I need to create an analysis for work in Excel, one of the things that have been asked is that I include a chart, this chart needs to show data grouped by a state given to it and a number of days passed since the date it was created.

I need to count how many of these bits of data there are that are older than 1 day, older than 2 days and so on, I have been looking at some way to combine COUNTIF/COUNTIFS and TODAY()-Date named in cell, this hasn't been fruitful, I am aware that I would just do the TODAY() bit in some seperate cells and work with the data from the but I would prefer a way to do it all in one, if there is some way to do such a thing in one formula it would be great, if not I'll just have to tell my boss no can do.

Thanks in advance for any help given, even if it is telling me it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=CountIfs(state, inputState, date, "<"&Today()-1, date, ">="&Today()-2)
```

That will give you all items holding `state` from the day before yesterday.

`state` and `date` are from your data. Replace with column references or (better) named range names.

Use `<` and `>=`, or `<=` and `>`, when slicing data by date (or any numeric amount). Using `<` and `>` or `<=` and `>=` forces you to think hard about gaps or overlap and that's no fun.

Answer (score 2):

Another method would be to use `SUMPRODUCT` to count the number of occurrences:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A20>=TODAY()-2))
```

The number `2` can be increased or decreased to vary the length of time from `TODAY()`. The `>=` symbols can also be changed based on whether you would like to count the number of dates before or after `TODAY()-2`.